# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to make my table view remember it's last position, so that after the app is run again, it will scroll to that position. to do this, in my `viewWillDisappear:` method, I get the first visible row number and save it to `NSUserDefaults`. then in my viewDidAppear I try to scroll to that row by sending `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to the table view. However I get a `NSRangeException`:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: section (0) beyond bounds (0).`

any help appreciated. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([userDefaults valueForKey:@"content_row"] != nil)
    {
        int rowToHighlight = [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"content_row"] intValue];
        NSIndexPath * ndxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToHighlight inSection:0];
        [contentTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ndxPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop  animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowPath = [[contentTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:selectedRowPath.row forKey:@"content_row"];
}
```

Comment: Could you post the bit of code that does the scrollToRowAtIndexPath and NSIndexPath creation?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Reload TableView data before calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

```
[contentTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the data isn't yet loaded (using a fetched results controller). My solution was to check `tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) > 0` first.

Comment: or if on a different thread, try this. `[tblView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]`

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that the contentTableView has not yet finished loading the data.

Comment: How do I get notified when it is finished?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the scrollToRowAtIndexPath was being called in viewDidLoad.  I have similar calls in viewDidAppear but instead of returning to a saved row number, I return to a saved key value which is saved in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Before calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath, I find that key value's row in the currently loaded data source.

Comment: Sweet! This actually helped get my gears spinning in the right direction. I elaborated in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on DyingCactus' answer. I'm a pretty new iOS developer and my situation was a little different, but as he said

> "It's possible that the contentTableView has not yet finished loading
>   the data"

While the answer was brief, it got my wheels turning and it was exactly what was happening for me.

**My Setup**

- UITableView is on ViewController "A"
- My app presents a new ViewController "B"
- On ViewController "B" a button is clicked, then data is added to the data source for the UITableView.
- From B's button click handler, `[tableView reloadData]` is called
- From B's button click handler, `[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:idxPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];` is called
- ViewController "B" is dismissed and "A" is presented again (showing the updated UITableView)

**Solution**

- The first problem I had to fix was to call `reloadData` on the main thread like so

  [tblView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
- The last problem was to change `waitUntilDone` to **true** (DUH!)

Yeah, so obviously for me, the contentTableView wasn't done loading the data because my reloadData call which is being run on the main thread was not explicitly set to block until the selector was done.

Hope this helps someone.