# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have a regular UITableView without any sections set up. I'm trying to automatically scroll to a row at a given index path like so...

```
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self getIndexToShow] inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

But when ran I get this error...

```
2010-07-19 18:07:58.391 Wrecking Ball[413:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: section (0) beyond bounds (0).'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Delegate method for number of sections...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any data in your data source, at that index path?

Comment: Yes, and I even substituted a int such as 0 instead of the method getIndexToShow just in case there was an error in my logic there.

Comment: If you have no sections, how can you have any rows? You'd have to have at least one section to have any rows, and for something to scroll to. Can you post your code for your table view delegate methods?

Comment: If you are using an Interface Builder file with a `UITableView` in it, do you have the `delegate` and the `dataSource` outlets wired up from the table view to the view controller?

Comment: I'm doing it with pure code, and I am setting both delegates. Everything works with the table except calling that method mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe try an `NSLog` of the `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self getIndexToShow] inSection:0]` statement, and perhaps log or `NSAssert()` other statements to verify their values. Perhaps you're getting a `nil` somewhere.

Comment: When I do that I get 0 for index and 0 for section just like I expect to get.

Comment: Well, I'm plumb out of ideas. I have found `NSLog` to be useful for checking values of things before methods get called.

Comment: At what point are you calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my delegate methods...

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
    {
        return [locationLevels count];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 447, 210);

    UILabel *levelName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170,6,280,17)];
    UILabel *levelStatus = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170,25,280,17)];
    UILabel *levelTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175,44,300,17)];
    UILabel *levelHeight = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175,63,300,17)];
    UILabel *levelScore = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175,82,300,17)];

    levelName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17.0f];
    levelStatus.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17.0f];
    levelTime.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17.0f];
    levelHeight.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17.0f];
    levelScore.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17.0f];

    levelName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    levelStatus.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    levelName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    levelStatus.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    levelTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    levelHeight.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    levelScore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    levelName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    levelStatus.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    levelTime.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    levelHeight.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    levelScore.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 

    levelName.tag = 1;
    levelStatus.tag = 2;
    levelTime.tag = 3;
    levelHeight.tag = 4;
    levelScore.tag = 5;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:levelName];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:levelStatus];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:levelTime];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:levelHeight];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:levelScore];

    [levelName release];
    [levelStatus release];
    [levelTime release];
    [levelHeight release];
    [levelScore release];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

    if([self levelCanBeShown:indexPath.row])
    {

    GameCard *card = [[[WBManager sharedManager]currentUser]getGameCardForLevel:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *levelName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *levelStatus = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *levelTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *levelHeight = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    UILabel *levelScore = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    levelName.text = [self getLevelStringForIntValue:indexPath.row];
    levelStatus.text = card.score <= 0 ? @"Incomplete" : @"Complete";

    if(card.score != 0)
    {
        levelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i",card.score];
        levelTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best Time: %i mins %i secs",card.time/60,card.time%60];
        levelHeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lowest Height: %i",card.height];
    }

    else
    {
        levelScore.text = @"Score: -";
        levelTime.text = @"BestTime: -";
        levelHeight.text = @"Lowest Height: -";
    }

    UIImage *screenshot = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"WSimg%i",indexPath.row+1] ofType:@"PNG"]];

    cell.imageView.image = screenshot;

    [screenshot release];

    }

    else
    {
        UILabel *levelName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *levelStatus = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *levelTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        UILabel *levelHeight = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
        UILabel *levelScore = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

        levelName.text = [self getLevelStringForIntValue:indexPath.row];
        levelStatus.text = @"LOCKED";
        levelTime.text = @"";
        levelHeight.text = @"";
        levelScore.text = @"";

        UIImage *screenshot = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"WSimg%i",indexPath.row+1] ofType:@"PNG"]];

        cell.imageView.image = screenshot;

        [screenshot release];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 110;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method?

As as aside, you should edit your original question to add code. This is the answer part of the page. Just click on "edit" underneath your question to edit it.

Comment: Take a look at the data source delegate method list here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: I posted the -numberOfSectionsInTableView: up above.

Answer (score 0):

did you reloadData before scrolling to specific row? here is the same problem with slution, which I just implemented and it is working well :)
[uitableview scrolling solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480092/uitableview-scrolltorowatindexpath-problem)